# atributo dataType AJAX - JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Sei que com o dataType definido para XML, ele entende que o retorno é XML e posso navegar pelo objeto retornado como se navega-se pela DOM, então, defini ele como HTML(`dataType:"html"`), e eu esperava que o retorno dele fosse de fato um documento, que eu pudesse navegar, mas retorna vazio as tags HTML, veja meu código:

```
$.ajax({
url:"test_login.php",
method:"POST",
dataType:"html",
data: {acao:"login",pass:pass,email:email},

success:function(data){
alert(
    $(data).find("html").text()
    );  // retorna vazio.


}
```

Então, o que estou errando?

Comment: o que envias do PHP para o ajax?

Comment: uma página HTML inteira, o retorno existe, eu vi na resposta e de fato ele retorna a página na requisição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na documentação do [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) pode ler-se:

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

Basicamente isso quer dizer que páginas inteiras não podem ser importadas via AJAX, nem via `jQuery(stringDePáginaInteira)`, e que elementos do html dessa string como `html`, `head` e `title` são removidos.

Daí que `$(data).find("html")` vai dar vazio.

A maneira correta, e a razão de o ajax ser util, é pedir via ajax só os dados minimos necessários. Senão mais vale carregar de novo a página ou uma iFrame com esse conteúdo. E caso sejam necessário parâmetros via GET.

Dito isto, é possivel importar HTML via ajax, mas nesse caso é melhor usar tags html mais seguras, no fundo tudo o que pode estar dentro de `body`.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/11ocj5m5/

(e repara que o primeiro elemento passado nem sequer é o `body`)

Comment: Perfeita resposta @Sergio, dessa eu nem imaginava, valeu pela ajuda.